# How to drag and drop a group of rectangles in svg in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, drag-and-drop

I worked based on  [this](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/1197731)  drag and drop example :

I want to drag a group. I placed both rectangles in single group and now want to drag and drop whole group, in my code drag and drop  works on single rectangle but not on group.

and here is my code :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js">  </script>

  <title>Drag And Drop</title>
  </head>
  <body>  

    <div id="viz"></div>

     <script type="text/javascript">

     var vizSVG = d3.select("#viz")
              .append("svg")
             .attr("width", 400)
              .attr("height", 300); 





var group =d3.select("svg")
                .append("g")
                .attr("id","group1")
                .attr("x",50)
                .attr("y", 140)
                //.attr("fill", "yellow")
            //  .call(d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", move));


group.append("rect")
    .attr("id", "bluerect")
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 140)
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("stroke", "red")
      .attr("fill", "blue")
      .attr("opacity","0.5")
   .call(d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", move));



    group.append("rect")
    .attr("id", "redrect")
    .attr("x", 110)
    .attr("y", 140)
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .call(d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", move));


    function move(){
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);

        var dragTarget = d3.select(this);

        dragTarget
        .attr("x", function(){;return d3.event.dx + parseInt(dragTarget.attr("x"))})
        .attr("y", function(){return d3.event.dy +                        parseInt(dragTarget.attr("y"))});
        };

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use transform on the group element instead of setting the x, y  attributes. <g transform="translate(x, y)">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `x` or `y` property in SVG [group elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g). To position them, you have to use [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform):

```
d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
//the x and y positions here --------------------^  -------^
```

Besides that, `<g>` elements are only containers. In the following demo (using `transform` to position the group, as already explained), for instance, you have to click in one of the rectangles to drag the whole group: clicking in the space between them has no effect.

```js
var g = d3.select("g")
  .datum({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  })
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + 
      (d.x = d3.event.x) + "," + (d.y = d3.event.y) + ")")
    }))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect x="40" y="10" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
    <rect x="60" y="40" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
    <rect x="30" y="35" width="20" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Gerardo what if I want to keep these rectangles within SVG boundary?

Comment: @NullPointer I see you already have an answer for your question.

Comment: yeah got that.. Thank you

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I've another question there, Can you please help me out with that?